# s3cmd get recursive equivalent command for s3Express(windows)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need the equivalent command of "s3cmd get --recursive"(of Linux or Mac) for s3Express(Windows)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) is available for Windows, Mac and Linux. It includes a recursive copy command and also a useful `sync` command that will only copy new or modified files.

See: [AWS CLI S3 documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#cli-aws-s3)

Answer (score 0):

You can find more details from this pdf file: http://www.s3express.com/docs/s3express_backup.pdf

To summarize, the command syntax you are looking for is:

get  "" -s -onlydiff

the -s is the s3cmd --recursive equivalent
the -onlydiff is the s3cmd sync equivalent